# pmatch is not documented fully

Tags: r, string-matching

The following behavior of pmatch in R base is documented because duplicates.ok=FALSE, so the first "Geek" in tables (second argument) is not considered when we match the second element of "x" (first argument)

```
pmatch(c("Geek", "Geek"), c("Geek", "Geek"))
[1] 1 2
```

But it is surprising the following

```
pmatch(c("Geek", "Gee"), c("Geek", "Geek"))
[1] 1 2
```

and the following

```
pmatch(c("Geek", "Gee"), c("Geek", "Geek", "Geek"))
[1]  1 NA
```

So violation of uniqueness for exact match is not an issue, but violation of uniqueness for partial match is an issue.

Armed with this assumption

```
pmatch(c("Gee", "Gee"), c("Geek", "Geek"))
[1] NA NA
```

is reasonable.

And here

```
pmatch(c("Gee", "Geek"), c("Geek", "Geek"))
[1] 2 1
```

is also reasonable because exact matches run first.

Is my understanding correct? Does documentation needs enhancement?
Because the duplicates.ok=TRUE is very detailed but the dual is slim.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the documentation could be clearer. That said, to me it fully describes the exact behaviour of the function (just not in an easily understood way). Here’s what the documentation says, slightly reformatted (but without changing the wording!) to make it clearer. The function operates in two consecutive steps:

> 1. exact matches are considered, and the positions of the *first* exact matches are recorded.
> 2. Then *unique* partial matches are considered, and if found recorded.

So: for *exact matches*, `pmatch()` allows multiple hits, and records the first one. But for *partial matches* it only allows *unique* matches. If a partial match is not unique, it does not count.

This behaviour is identical for both values of `duplicates.ok`, which is why the second paragraph in the Details doesn’t repeat it.

With that out of the way, we can simplify your examples as follows (by removing the first, exact match). I hope this makes it clearer:

```
pmatch("Geek", "Geek")
# [1] 1

pmatch("Gee", "Geek")
# [1] 1

# No *unique* partial match!
pmatch("Gee", c("Geek", "Geek"))
# [1] NA
```